# Jordan Content of the set $\{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, ... \}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have the following definition of the Jordan Content of set $E$ -

inf $\{ \sum_{i=1}^n |I_i| : n \in \mathbb{N}, I_1, I_2, ..., I_n$ intervals such that $E \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n\}$

That seems to me that the Jordan Content of the set $\{1, \frac{1}{2},  \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8},  ... \}$ is undefined as this is an infinite set and the Jordan Content uses a finite number of intervals so it is impossible to find enough intervals to contain all the elements of that set?

If we did take the jordan Content to work over an infinite amount set like this it seems the value would be $0$ as we would have an infinite number of arbitrary small intervals?

Is my understanding correct on these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.

First of all, $(0,1]$ is a single interval contains the set.

Second, you're taking the infimum over all these values; **in particular, just because the Jordan content is some number $c$ doesn't mean that there exists some finite number of intervals $I_1,\ldots, I_n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n |I_i|=c$.**

Think about it some more before you peek at this:

> Given any $\epsilon>0$, if you can show that there is a covering of the set by finitely many intervals of total length less than $\epsilon$, then you will have shown that the Jordan content is zero.

Answer (score 0):

First take care of the infinite tale of the sequence by a sufficiently small interval, and then cover finitely many remaining terms by a finite number of small intervals.

> Let $\epsilon >0$ be given and find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2^{-N}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
> Now let $I_N=(0,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ and for $0 \leq j \leq N-1$ define $I_j=(2^{-j}-\frac{\epsilon}{2N},2^{-j}+\frac{\epsilon}{2N})$.